# Как сделать заливку?

Tags: html, css

Есть код - https://jsfiddle.net/npt6o30m/

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы атрибут checked срабатывал не только для текста, но и для всей кнопки в целом. Я понимаю, что я должен делать не `.question-answers label input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .label-text`, а так

`.question-answers input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label` но почему-то это не работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать заливку всей кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.question-answers input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label
```

не работает, потому что:

> Комбинатор '~' выбирает элементы, которые находятся на этом же уровне вложенности, после указанного элемента, с тем же родителем.

а у вас инпут лежит внутри лейбла.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

input:checked ~ label {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="qwe">
  <label for="qwe">Нажми</label>
</div>
```

Вариант с той же разметкой:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  position: relative;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

label:focus-within {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-answers">
<label><input type="radio"><span class="label-text">Нажми</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно ли сделать это не меняя html разметки?

Comment: @ИванИванович добавил.

Comment: все понял, спасибо

Comment: а не можно сделать как-то не через focus-within, потому что при клике в другое место заливка спадает, а если поменять на просто focus такое не сработает

Comment: я могу скрипт написать

Comment: буду очень благодарен!

Comment: А почему нельзя менять разметку? Просто это будет очень нелепо смотреться.

Comment: разметку не смогу поменять, пускай будет нелепо смотреться, я поправлю сам в дальнейшем

Comment: Хотя не надо друг, я сделал немного по другому, благодарю!

Comment: на всякий случай https://jsfiddle.net/osd4m9yp/ . Но сразу говорю, это выглядит очень глупо )

Comment: Спасибо еще раз